# Ошибка после обновления базы данных

Tags: entity-framework, миграция, codefirst

После добавления нового поля в базу.  При запуске программы возникает ошибка 'Базовая модель контекста изменилась с момента создания базы данных. Рассмотрите возможность обновления базы данных с помощью Code First Migration. Но новое поле как раз и было добавлено таким способом. Подскажите пожалуйста что с этим делать.

Comment: после `add-migration` делали `update-database`?

Comment: Да. Откатила миграцию. Вернула как было. Добавила пустую миграцию, а потом свою. Так работает. Но. Через некоторое время опять эта ошибка вылезает.